# Calculo de pedágio por quilograma

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, preciso fazer um calculo de pedágio baseado no quilograma. A cada **100Kg** o valor do pedágio deve ser adicionando

> Ex:
>
> 50kg = 6.42
>
> 100kg = 6.42
>
> 101kg = 12.84
>
> 200kg = 12.84
>
> 299kg = 12.84
>
> 300kg = 19.26
>
> ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pesoTotaldaNota").focusout(function() {
        peso = "20.000"; // = 20Kg
        echoPedagio = "6.42"        
    }); 
});
```

Preciso mostrar o resultado no `input`

```
<input name="pedagio" type="text" class="form-control" id="pedagio" value="" required>
```

**Outro exemplo** `Até 100kg = 6.42` `Até 200kg = 6.42+6.42` `Até 200kg = 6.42+6.42+6.42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outra alternativa:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pedagio").change(function () {
        var peso = parseFloat(this.value);
        var pedagio = 6.42;
        var extra = Math.ceil(peso / 100) * pedagio;
        this.value = peso + extra;
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3b7b5jzm/

O exemplo está aplicado ao input. O que faz é saber quantas vezes o peso é maior que `100` e arredondar para multiplicar pelo `pedagio`. Esse valor é então somado ao resultado final como um "extra".

Comment: Fiz um pequena modificação http://jsfiddle.net/3b7b5jzm/1/, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Montei um pequeno exemplo pra você:

```
<input name="pedagio" type="text" class="form-control" id="pedagio" value="" required>
<a id="pesoTotaldaNota">Calcular</a>
```

Nessa função ele tem o peso de 100Kg e o valor do Pedágio de 100Kg.

Divide o Peso por 100, para ver quantos 100 cabe dentro de 200 Kg, por exemplo.
Cabe 2, multiplicando pelo valor do pedágio de 100 Kg.

Depois ele verifica se sobrou algum RESTO na divisão pelo símbolo de %.
Nesse caso não sobra nada.

Mas troque o 200 por 101, ou 201 e verá o resultado.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pesoTotaldaNota").click(function() {
        peso = "101";
        var valor = 0;
        var resto = 0;
        echoPedagio = "6.42";
        
        if(peso >= 100){
            valor = (peso / 100) * echoPedagio;
            resto = peso % 100;
            if(resto > 0)
            valor = (echoPedagio * resto) + valor;
        }
        else
            valor = 6.42;
        
        $('#pedagio').val(valor.toFixed(2));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: funcionou, mas percebi um problema, quando o valor é menor que 100. Veja http://jsfiddle.net/zohfk3rq/

Comment: E o que você quer que aconteça quando o peso for menor que 100 ?

Comment: Outro exemplo `Até 100kg = 6.42` `Até 200kg = 6.42+6.42` `Até 200kg = 6.42+6.42+6.42`

Comment: Alterei a função.

Comment: Muito obrigado diego, mas aqui funcionou melhor http://jsfiddle.net/3b7b5jzm/1/

Comment: Você é quem manda, cara. (y)

Comment: Sua resposta está bacana, mas acho que seu erro está em multiplicar o valor do pedágio pelo resto. Se houver resto, basta incluir 1 valor do pedágio (isto é: `valor = valor + echoPedagio`), pois isso significa que o peso já ultrapassou um múltiplo de 100 e um novo pedágio deve ser adicionado (pelo que eu entendi da pergunta). Vai ser o caso do valor 101, por exemplo.